# how to solve cauchy-euler differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$y^{\prime\prime}+P(x)y'+Z(x)y=0$
is second order homogeneous differential equation. 
if yp is particular solution then $y=y_p\cdot u$, we can transform $u$ into first order differential equation. 

If $m(m-1)+mxP+x^2Q=0$, $y_p=x^m$
if $m^2+mP+Q=0$, $yp=e^{mx}$

question:
1.$(x-1)y"-xy'+y=0$, find $y$ 
here I don't understand, the answer in the book said that $m^2(x-1)-mx+1=m(1)(mx-m-1)=0$ so $m=1$ and $y=e^x$
I'm stuck here i know that if you want to use cauchy euler diferential equation, we must make it like this $x^2y"+xy'-y=0$ but here it is $(x-1)y"-xy'+y=0$ should i change the x-1? can someone explain how to get $m^2(x-1)-mx+1=m(1)(mx-m-1)=0$ ??
thanks

Comment: That equation isn't Cauchy-Euler...

Comment: @SeanRoberson ok so whats the idea to solve this?

Comment: You'll need to use power series: use the ansatz $y = \sum a_j x^j$ and manipulate. I suggest reading about it; I can't give details now.

Comment: @SeanRoberson but the book said that $yp= e^mx$ , and i didnt understand how to produce this $m^2(x-1)-mx+1=m(1)(mx-m-1)=0$

Comment: Did you try plugging $e^{mx}$ into the equation?

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes it is said that $y=e^{mx}$ was the particular solution

Answer (score 1):

I think the book is trying to say that if you try the particular solution $y=e^{mx}$
you get ...
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}  
(x-1)(m^2e^{mx})  - x(m e^{mx})+ e^{mx} &=&0
\\ \left[  (m^2-m)x -m^2+1 \right]e^{mx}=0
\end{eqnarray*} $$

For this to be an identity in $x$ the coefficients of all powers of $x$ in the bracket must vanish so

$$m^2 - m = 0 \implies m \in \{0,1\}  $$
and 
$$ -m^2+1=0 \implies m \in \{-1,1\}  $$

by happy coincidence $m=1$ makes both coefficients vanish so $y=e^x$ is a particular  solution to the original ODE.

Comment: hello thanks!!! what do you mean by all powers of  x in bracket must vanish? and how to make it vanish?

Comment: $[ (m^2-m)x -m^2+1]$ here actually i try to find the root, the result is $(m-1)(mx-m-1)$ , is this you mean to make x vanish, so m=1? can you explain why the x is not used?

Comment: yes - you have corrected the typo in the original post and have factored the bracket in a different way , but you can still see that the equation will be satisfied for any $x$ provided that $m=1$.

Comment: oh i got it! to make $e^{mx}$ as a solution, $[ (m^2-m)x -m^2+1]=0 $ and then you will get m=1 either by factorize or your way, so $yp=e^x$ is particular solution, so the book is trying to said that if it is a particular solution so the equation will be same as zero, and after we know one of the particular solution, we can find the general solution by using reduction order, is this right??